# How to impute missing values for a variable with values simulated from a regression equation in R for this dataset?

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, missing-data

I have the following sample of large dataset. Through the heckman selection model, I have estimated a regression model for this data by the following code

Now I want to impute the missing values for the variable salary with the estimated equation. I have created the following code that simulates a value from the regression equation.

But now I am stuck on the idea how to replace the simulated values from this regression equation with the missing values from salary. Any idea how to do this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this using `ifelse`

```
dflapop$salary2 <- ifelse(is.na(dflapop$salary2), simsalary, dflapop$salary
```

)

Comment: I get the following error when doing this: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, salary2, value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1492

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo on my answer. Could you try again?